# Git remote rejecting push (failed to update ref)

Tags: git

I have been working with this repository for months now. No issues whatsoever, no changes made before this started happening.

This is a private repository stored on a remote server (That I can remote into if needed). My local project is up to date with the current branch. However, as soon as I attempt to push it fails for some unknown reason. I have checked all of the other stackoverflow questions, they are all due to not locking or bare/nonbare or something else, all of which is mentioned in the log after they push. This is a different issue.

```
C:\APPNAME>git push
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 463 bytes | 463.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 4), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: couldn't set 'refs/heads/master'
To //APPNAME/reposit
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (failed to update ref)
error: failed to push some refs to '//APPNAME/reposit'
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue locally or on the remote end.
Any ideas or suggestions?

Comment: can you do a git fetch followed by git status to see if you have the tip of remote repo?

Comment: C:\HouApp>git fetch

C:\HouApp>git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

Comment: Can you look at the log files on the git server?

Comment: You will need to ssh into the remote host and poke around. This is not a typical failure. My first guess is that someone on the remote machine did this kind of ssh-and-poke-around and left some files set to the wrong owner (owned by root for instance), and/or messed with file permissions on some directory or directories.

Comment: @torek Your comment turned out to be correct. You should submit it as an answer so I can correctly credit you.

Comment: The part about the file permissions. Turned out write access had been removed from my local account and given to my admin account instead. I would have had to push with elevated permissions or (what I did instead) get write privileges added back to my local, non admin account.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does not look like any of the more normal failure modes.  My guess was that someone on the remote machine left some files or permissions set wrongly.

That turned out to be correct (see comments below the post): someone had removed write access from the local account and given it to an admin account instead.  Restoring write privileges to the local account was the fix in this case.